# Testing callback of an asynchronous call Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, callback, promise

Hi I want to test if a callback has been called. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly but here is what I have:

```js
var Git = function () {
    this.GetGitUser = function (username, callback) {
        $.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username).then(function (data) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Here is the unit test:

```js
describe('Git', function () {
    it('should call callback', function () {
        // Arrange
        var git = new Git();
        var callbackMock = jasmine.createSpy();

        spyOn(git, "GetGitUser").and.callFake(function (callback) {
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });

        // Act
        git.GetGitUser(callbackMock);

        // Assert
        expect(callbackMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

Thanks in advance!